# Create uninitialized SSE value

Tags: c++, sse, intrinsics

I'm writing a function for 3 value horizontal sum, and the compiler generates suboptimal code. The algorithm works like this: (`a,b,c` are values, and `_` is don't care)

```
a b c _  --movhlps->  a b _ _  --shufps-> a _ _ _
                      c _ _ _             b _ _ _
                                          c _ _ _
```

Followed by two `addps`.

But when I write the code with intrinsics, I can't get it to generate assembly that ignores the value of the other elements.

The obvious thing,

```
__m128 sum3_a(__m128 r)
{
  __m128 b = _mm_movehl_ps(__m128(), r);
  //...
```

generates

```
sum3_a(float __vector(4)):
    xorpd    %xmm2, %xmm2
    movapd   %xmm0, %xmm3
    unpckhpd %xmm2, %xmm3    # xmm3 = xmm3[1],xmm2[1]
```

So it looks like `_mm128()` generates a register filled with zeros (the `xorpd`).

I can get rid of the `xorpd` like this,

```
__m128 sum3_b(__m128 r)
{
  __m128 b = _mm_movehl_ps(r, r);
  //...
```

But that gives me (to be fair exactly what I asked for),

```
sum3_b(float __vector(4)):
    movaps  %xmm0, %xmm2
    movhlps %xmm2, %xmm2     # xmm2 = xmm2[1,1]
```

But all I want is

```
sum3(float __vector(4)):
    movhlps %xmm2, %xmm0
```

How do I write that in C++?

Comment: Well, with `__m128()` you are _asking for_ zero (or default, depending on the C++ version -- which however is zero-initialization in the case of a non-class type with implicit default constructor, too) initialization. So it's no surprise that it's initialized to zero. Just create a local variable and don't initialize it, if that's what you want?

Comment: @Damon That appears to generate the same code as calling it with the same variable twice.

Comment: Basically, you don't. A reg-reg move is nearly free anyway though, so it's not that bad.

Comment: @Damon: I tried it (with gcc -O3, not g++):   `__m128 b =  _mm_movehl_ps(b, r);` produces a `pxor` to initialize `tmp`.

Answer (score 1):

gcc 4.9.2 produces a `pxor` initializer for `b` when using a `__m128 b = _mm_movehl_ps(b, r);`

`movhlps` runs on the shuffle port on Intel/AMD CPUs.  On Nehalem and later, there is extra latency (bypass delay) for using an integer shuffle between FP instructions, though.  `pshufd` would be ideal to broadcast the element you want, since it doesn't read its destination.  On Sandybridge and later, it would add 1 cycle of latency (or 2, if the data to be shuffled came from an FP instruction that hasn't finished executing.  (i.e. this is part of the critical path.))  On Nehalem, penalties are double.  On AMD and Core2, there's no extra penalty (all shuffles are integer-domain.)

gcc produces mediocre code (with a lot of `movaps` uops) when compiling a non-intrinsic version (with no `-march`, so all it can assume is SSE2 as part of baseline amd64).  It makes quite good code with `-march=sandybridge` or higher, getting it to use 3-operand AVX versions of vector ops.

```
float sum3_b(__m128 r) {
    return r[0] + r[1] + r[2];
}

sum3_b:  # baseline x86-64
.LFB2226:
        movaps  %xmm0, %xmm1    # r, tmp93
        movaps  %xmm0, %xmm2    #, D.14010
        shufps  $85, %xmm0, %xmm1       #, r, tmp93
        addss   %xmm1, %xmm2    # D.14010, D.14010
        movaps  %xmm0, %xmm1    # r, tmp96
        unpckhps        %xmm0, %xmm1    # r, tmp96
        addss   %xmm1, %xmm2    # D.14010, D.14010
        movaps  %xmm2, %xmm0    # D.14010, D.14010
        ret

sum3_b:  # -march=sandybridge
.LFB2226:
        vshufps $85, %xmm0, %xmm0, %xmm1        #, r, r,
        vaddss  %xmm1, %xmm0, %xmm1     # D.14011, D.14011, D.14011
        vunpckhps       %xmm0, %xmm0, %xmm0     # r, r,
        vaddss  %xmm0, %xmm1, %xmm0     # D.14011, D.14011, D.14011
        ret
```

I didn't see an intrinsic that casts a single float to a `__m128`, just the other way around (`float _mm_cvtss_f32 (__m128 a)`).  On pre-Sandybridge, denormals and NaNs can slow down FP operations a *lot*, so you should make sure you use scalar adds to avoid the risk of `addps` slowdowns with weird data in the 4th element of the vector.

I don't have any great ideas for writing this with intrinsics without using AVX shuffles.  (_mm_permute_ps `vpermilps` is like `pshufd` for floats: only one input reg.  You might as well just use `vshufps` unless you need to fold a load into it, though, because 3-operand VEX encoding means you can `vshufps` a register with a different destination.)